# Constraint Error with instance definition

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define the following class & instance

```
class Adder a where  
    plus :: a -> a -> a  

instance Adder Num where  
    plus x y = x + y
```

But I am getting this error

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘Num’
The first argument of ‘Adder’ should have kind ‘*’,
  but ‘Num’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’
In the instance declaration for ‘Adder Num’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Later I would like to also define

```
instance Adder String where  
    plus x y = x + y
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution for `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any type that is an instance of `Num` to be an instance of `Adder`, you can achieve that like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class Adder a where
    plus :: a -> a -> a

instance Num a => Adder a where   
    plus = (+)
```

to add a `String` instance, you need one more language extension

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

class Adder a where
    plus :: a -> a -> a

instance Num a => Adder a where    
    plus = (+)

instance Adder String where
    plus = (++)
```